# Model code to module: wrong number of args, class/ instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I am trying to move some model code to a module.

The original model method:

I am trying to move some model code to a module.

The original model method:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  def book_royalty(period='enddate', basis="Net receipts")
    #stuff
  end
end
```

So I add

```
include Calculation
```

and move the method to a module:

```
module Calculation
  def book_royalty(period='enddate', basis="Net receipts")
    #stuff
  end
end
```

But now I'm getting

> wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)

This is the error I also get if I make the method in the book.rb model a class method i.e. if I make the method name `self.book_royalty(args)`.

Am I inadvertently making the methods moved to the module class methods? I'm using `include` in book.rb, not `extend`. How can I get the parent model to successfully include the module's methods?

### Edit

`book_royalty` is called in the Royaltystatement model.

book.rb:

```
attr_accessor :book_royalty
```

royaltystatement.rb:

```
def initialize_arrays
  @royalty  = []
  ...
end

def sum_at_book_level(contract)
  contract.books.where(:exclude_from_royalty_calc => false).each do |book| 
    book.book_royalty("enddate", basis)
    @royalty.push(book.book_royalty("enddate", basis))
    # etc
end
```

Comment: How are you calling `book_royalty`?

Comment: edited to preserve formatting...

Comment: Genius, ta. So can you explain? Presumably, adding attr_accessor makes the method a class method automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explanation:

Your module defines a method `book_royalty` that takes two arguments. Then, a couple of lines after the inclusion of that module you use class macro `attr_accessor` which defines two methods,

```
def book_royalty
  @book_royalty
end

def book_royalty= val
  @book_royalty = val
end
```

This effectively **overwrites** your `book_royalty` from the module. Now it accepts no arguments. Hence the error

> wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)

when trying to execute line

```
book.book_royalty("enddate", basis)
```

You **don't need** `attr_accessor` or anything else in order to use a method from included module. It becomes available automatically.